# Search in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make a search function in the following array:

```
array(      
    array("key" => "net_sale",         "value" => "NET SALE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_calls", "value" => "Productive Calls"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_value",  "value" => "DROP SIZE VALUE"),
    array("key" => "sku",              "value" => "SKU PER BILL"),
    array("key" => "net_amount",       "value" => "Net Amount"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_crtn",   "value" => "DROP SIZE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_pops",  "value" => "PRODUCTIVE POPS"),
    array("key" => "scheduled_pops",   "value" => "SCHEDULED POPS") 
);
```

This function will return the position for any key searched. (for example for search "net_amount" it will return 4)

Comment: Sounds great! What have you tried?

Comment: I loop through the array to search , but this is not an efficient way

Comment: Looping would seem to be the only choice in your case

Comment: ...by the way, you're probably going to confuse yourself by calling the 2nd key of each sub-array a 'value', yet it's still just a 'key'...

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0N00Jq

Comment: @asprin wouldn't it make more sense if you added it as an answer...?

Comment: @webeno There are already 8 answers out there. No use clogging that space even more.

Comment: @asprin but you're using comments for an answer, better to put things where they belong, it's just the order of things... to my view at least

Comment: If I will change the array format, is there any PHP function I can use for searching? (to avoid loop)

Comment: @ShehzadBilal how would you change the array format and why would you want to avoid looping?

Comment: By replacing key with actual key and value. I want to avoid loop because array is large I have use just write 8 .

Comment: "By replacing key with actual key and value." - elaborate on this pls, maybe give an example? by the way, you might have to update your question or, better yet, place a new one with your specific requirements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function search($array,$key_value) {
   foreach($array AS $key => $value) {
     if($value['key'] == $key_value) return $key;
   }
}
echo search($arr,'net_amount'); //$arr contains the array you gave as example
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array where the key is actually a key and the value is the value.

```
$map = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $value = $values[$i];
    $map[$value['key']] = $i;
}

$net_amount_pos = $map['net_amount'];
```

Comment: you're returning the value of the `value` key though the OP wanted to have the number of the array having the value as the key 'key' (if i understood correctly)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
<?php
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

However in your case there is a simpler solution. Instead of using "key" and "value" which is kind of a waste, format your array like:

```
array('net_sale' =>'NET SALE CRTN','productive_calls'=>'Productive Calls') //etc.
```

then you can pull out the key directly instead of needing to search for it...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments on the question, I don't believe the way you're currently storing the data is the best possible. Nonetheless just loop through each array and check if either contains the string you're searching for

```
function searchArrays($search){
    $return = array();
    $data = array(      
        array("key" => "net_sale",         "value" => "NET SALE CRTN"),
        array("key" => "productive_calls", "value" => "Productive Calls"),
        array("key" => "drop_size_value",  "value" => "DROP SIZE VALUE"),
        array("key" => "sku",              "value" => "SKU PER BILL"),
        array("key" => "net_amount",       "value" => "Net Amount"),
        array("key" => "drop_size_crtn",   "value" => "DROP SIZE CRTN"),
        array("key" => "productive_pops",  "value" => "PRODUCTIVE POPS"),
        array("key" => "scheduled_pops",   "value" => "SCHEDULED POPS") 
    );

    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        if(stristr($v['key'], $search) || stristr($v['value'], $search)){
            $return[] = $k;
        }
    }

    return $return;
};
print_r(searchArrays('net'));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is following code:

```
$test  = array(      
    array("key" => "net_sale",         "value" => "NET SALE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_calls", "value" => "Productive Calls"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_value",  "value" => "DROP SIZE VALUE"),
    array("key" => "sku",              "value" => "SKU PER BILL"),
    array("key" => "net_amount",       "value" => "Net Amount"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_crtn",   "value" => "DROP SIZE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_pops",  "value" => "PRODUCTIVE POPS"),
    array("key" => "scheduled_pops",   "value" => "SCHEDULED POPS") 
);
$index = keyval($test,"net_amount");

echo $index;
function keyval($test,$val)
{
$i = null;
    foreach($test as $index=>$t)
    {
        //echo $t['key'];
        if($t['key']==$val){ $i = $index;}
    }
    return $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

**Define a Function**

```
function checkPosition($needle, $arrData)
{
  $i=0;
   foreach($arrData as $data){

      if(in_array($needle,$data))
        { return $i; }

      $i++;
   }


}
```

**Calling a Function-**

```
echo checkPosition('net_amount',$test);
Output : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
$array = array(      
    array("key" => "net_sale",         "value" => "NET SALE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_calls", "value" => "Productive Calls"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_value",  "value" => "DROP SIZE VALUE"),
    array("key" => "sku",              "value" => "SKU PER BILL"),
    array("key" => "net_amount",       "value" => "Net Amount"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_crtn",   "value" => "DROP SIZE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_pops",  "value" => "PRODUCTIVE POPS"),
    array("key" => "scheduled_pops",   "value" => "SCHEDULED POPS") 
);

function search($term, $array) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
        if ($array[$i]['key'] == $term) return $i;
    }
}

echo search("net_amount", $array);
```

And **[here is a demo](http://3v4l.org/P4lbq)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=array(
    array("key" => "net_sale",         "value" => "NET SALE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_calls", "value" => "Productive Calls"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_value",  "value" => "DROP SIZE VALUE"),
    array("key" => "sku",              "value" => "SKU PER BILL"),
    array("key" => "net_amount",       "value" => "Net Amount"),
    array("key" => "drop_size_crtn",   "value" => "DROP SIZE CRTN"),
    array("key" => "productive_pops",  "value" => "PRODUCTIVE POPS"),
    array("key" => "scheduled_pops",   "value" => "SCHEDULED POPS")
);

$search_key="sku";


for($count=0; $count<=count($data); ++$count)
{

    if(strcmp($data[$count]["key"], $search_key)==0)
    {
        echo $data[$count]["value"];
    }

}
```